# Pick row that has multiple other rows in adjacent table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `conversations`. Beside that, I have a table called `conversation_participants`.

When users create a conversation, they pick which other users they want to make it with. I do, tough, want to check before creating a new conversation, that it doesn't already exists with that batch of participants - if so I just want to reuse the existing one.

So my question is. How do I find a row in `conversation` that has the exact relations in `conversation_participants`.

My table looks like this (simplified).

```
   | conversations       |
   | ------------------- |
   | id      | int (pk)  |
   | created | timestamp |
   | ------------------- |
```

```
   | conversation_participants                |
   | ---------------------------------------- |
   | id           | int (pk)                  |
   | created      | timestamp                 |
   | conversation | int (fk to conversations) |
   | user         | int (fk to users)         |
   | read         | timestamp                 |
   | ---------------------------------------- |
```

Now the question is. How do I find the row in `conversation` that has the exact set of users in `conversation_participants`? It must be the exact set – not just a subset.

Comment: provide some sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: You need a foreign key from `conversation_participants` to `conversations`, else you cannot associate participants with a conversation.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Oh, yes. I have that. I just forgot to put it in. I'll add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  If you construct the list of participants *in order* in a string or array, you can use:

```
select cp.conversation
from conversation_participants cp
group by cp.conversation
having string_agg(user order by user, ',') = '1,2,3,4';
```

You can also do this without strings or arrays:

```
select cp.conversation
from conversation_participants cp
where user in (1, 2, 3, 4)
group by cp.conversation
having count(*) = 4;  -- all four users
```

If you pass the values in as an array:

```
select cp.conversation
from conversation_participants cp
where user i= any :ar
group by cp.conversation
having count(*) = cardinality(:ar)  -- all four users
```

Comment: Thx a lot for this answer! This was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Find all `conversations` that do **not** have a `conversation_participants` that is **not** in the list:

```
SELECT c.id
FROM conversations AS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM conversation_participants AS cp
                  WHERE cp.conversation = c.id
                    AND cp."user" NOT IN (/* list of users */));
```

Comment: Nice! This is exactly it. I assume I just need to remove `NOT` if I want to a conversation, where they ARE in the list?

Comment: No. You want a conversation where ALL participants are in the list. That is equivalent to finding a conversation where NOT ANY participant is NOT in the list. The way to determine if all objects have a certain property is to make sure that no objects doesn't have the property. The former cannot easily be written in SQL.